# Karate available for ecmascript-6

Tags: ecmascript-6, karate

Any idea about when ECMA 6 will be supported? I can see that I can't use string template or arrow functions like:

```
console.log(`foo ${fn()} bar`);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This may take a little while until [`Graal`](https://www.graalvm.org) makes it into the JVM. The `Nashorn` engine that Karate uses currently does not support ES6.

Meanwhile, it is not too bad. You are only the second or third person who has complained about this so far :P

Note that the `karate.log()` API takes comma delimited arguments.

```
* print 'a:', a, 'b:', b
* eval karate.log('a:', a, 'b:', b)
```

Comment: that's a good solution for karate syntax, but a constraint if you have to write javascript functions. Anyway we'll have to wait.